# how can calculate crc8_sae_j1850 for 4 bytes(00 00 0C 05) with the initial value 0xFF and the polynomial 0x1D?

Tags: c, search, software-design, crc

I want to read a hitags256 page with the command read_page(1100) 05(0000 0101), expecting crc8(1100 0010). For that I have to do crc8_sae_j1850 for 4 bytes (00 00 0C 05), with polynomial 0x1D and initial value 0xFF. Give me, please, an idea how to proceed.
I would also like, if possible, to send me the routine that solves this problem, which has the option to print the obtained value.
Thank you.

Documentation: [HITAG S Transponder IC](https://thierry-lequeu.fr/data/HITAG.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

*Update with documentation and expected CRC:*

I don't know where you got four bytes from. The CRC-8 is computed on 12 bits. Not 32. It is computed on the four-bit READ PAGE command `1100` and the eight-bit PADR `00000101`. I can use the C code right there in the documentation on page 46 to compute the CRC on those 12 bits:

```c
    unsigned char crc = 0xff;
    calc_crc(&crc, 0xc0, 4);
    calc_crc(&crc, 0x05, 8);
    printf("%02X\n", crc);
```

That prints `C2`, the expected CRC.

Note that less than eight bits need to be provided in the *high* bits of the second argument of `calc_crc()`.

By the way, the CRC being used here is *not* the SAE-J1850 CRC-8. That CRC has a final exclusive-or of `0xff`, whereas the CRC specified in the HITAG S documentation and that gives the correct answer here has a final exclusive-or of zero, i.e. no final exclusive or.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your reply. Yes, is C language. The final exclusive is 0x7A(for hitags). The initial value is 0xFF? So, can you complete your work with "main()....", which has the option "printf" to see crc value? My compiler is CCS and microcontroller is PIC18F14K22.            Thank you again.

Comment: If the final exclusive-or is not `0xff`, then it's not the CRC you named, the SAE-J1850 CRC-8.

Comment: Yes, this code uses the initial value `0xff`. It uses the final exclusive-or, `0xff`.

Comment: If you don't know how to use `printf()` in C, then you have no hope of being able to use this routine. You'll need to start by learning C.

Comment: Can you put a link to the documentaiton of the CRC you need in the question, that has this `0x7a` final exclusive-or?

Comment: Sorry, I was inspired by CRC8_SAE_J1850. I tested crc8 from 0x00 to 0x7A and that's how I found 0x7A which gives correct crc8, visualized on an oscilloscope with memory on a hitags reader.

Comment: int main() {
        CRCInit();

        printf("0x%2X\n", CalcCRC(buf,sizeof(buf)));

        return 0;
}
I use this printf() in another application. My 4 bytes 00 00 0C 05 is stored in flash memory in my case(pic18f...)?  Is about hitags256/2048 data sheet from NXP:   https://www.thierry-lequeu.fr/data/HITAG.pdf

Comment: There is C code right there in that document for computing the CRC! (Page 46.) Why are you posting a question here?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Because I don't know how to enter the data (00000C05) in this code to get crc8.

Comment: Do you see where that code has `0x2c, 0x68, 0x0D, 0xB4`?

Comment: Of course I saw it, but with my data (00000C05) and final XOR with 0x7A, I don't get the correct value of CRC8: C2

Comment: There is no final exclusive-or with `0x7A` in that code, or anywhere. I think you made that up. What is the expected CRC-8 value, and how do you know what the expected value is?

Comment: I have a hitags256 reader/writer that uses the em4095 driver, I analyzed the command signal of the rfid field when reading page 5 and found the codes for: read_page(1100), page 05 (0000 0101) and crc8(1100 0010).     I can send you a photo with the rfid field control signal on the oscilloscope.  I would prefer to continue the discussion, if possible, by email.  Thank you.

Comment: _That's_ what needs to be in the question. I added it.

Comment: Solved! The goal of the project is to create a low cost reader/writer for hitags, em4305, t5577, only with microcontroller, without em4095 or htrc110. Thank you for all and sorry if I didn't explain very well what I wanted.